# Referenced array to array yield size instead of actual array

Tags: perl

Probably a simple answer, but this has annoyed me for quite some time. I have a variable that looks to be a reference to an array of objects (hashes), i.e. the subroutine retrieving this array returns this

```
return \@my_entities;
```

All places I have looked states, in order to loop through these entities I need to do something like this

```
for my $obj (@{$ref}) {
   #do stuff
}
```

Why is it then if I do as above: @{$ref}, I get SCALAR "2" if I have 2 elements instead of the array? It's like @{$ref} gives me the size rather than the array.

EDIT: To elaborate more, it appears the operators work opposite in my context, if I do

```
scalar $ref
```

I get the array. and if I do

```
@($ref)
```

I get the length. Is there some hidden option somewhere that reverses the behavior?

I have only recently started working with perl and the code base is rather huge so it would be impossible to paste it all in here, but the gist of the trouble spot looks very similar to one of the answers below. Basically a sub returns a reference to an array/list and that list is being attempted looped through.

If I do this

```
sub f { 
   my @my_entities = @_;
   return \@my_entities;
}

my $ref = f(qw( a b c d ));
for my $obj (@{$ref}) {
   print $obj;
}
```

I get 4 as a result, it doesn't loop through elements. If I change @{$ref} to scalar $ref I get the a b c d listed.

Should be said I am using the Camelcade debugger to run this on a linux server through Webstorm on my laptop.

Comment: Generally you get `SCALAR 2` instead of the actual array if you are using it in scalar context (instead of list context).  Could you provide the actual example where you see this behavior?

Answer (score 6):

If you evaluate `@{$ref}` in scalar context, you will get the number of elements in the array referenced by `$ref` (just as if you had evaluated `@a` in scalar context).

If you evaluate `@{$ref}` in list context, you will get the elements of the array referenced by `$ref` (just as if you had evaluated `@a` in list context).

In the code you posted, you are doing the latter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub f { 
   my @my_entities = @_;
   return \@my_entities;
}

my $ref = f(qw( a b c d ));
for my $obj (@{$ref}) {
   say $obj;
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference here between array references and actual arrays. If you evaluate an array in list context, you get the array elements. If you evaluate an array in scalar context, you get the number of elements in the array.

```
my @array = qw[A B C];
print "@array"; # list context gives 'A B C'
print scalar @array; # scalar context gives 3

my $array_ref = \@array;
print "@$array_ref"; # list context gives 'A B C'
print scalar @$array_ref; # scalar context gives 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that is what I have seen in all texts on the subject. I should add, in my case the behavior appears to be completely opposite. If I do scalar $ref I get the array/list, if I do @{$ref} I get the size. Weird. The code base is rather huge, so I am wondering if there is something in there that reverses the behavior.

Comment: If you use `scalar $ref` you will get the array reference, not the array elements. The behaviour of `@{ref}` will depend on the context in which your expression is evaluated. There is no way to "reverse the behaviour". It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a short, but complete, example that exhibits the behaviour that is confusing you.

Comment: Updated the original text.

Comment: @aggaton: Weird. That displays `abcd` as I would expect.